# How can I create a Scheduled Event for a lambda function using the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-lambda

The AWS CLI does not have an option to schedule a lambda function. This is possible via the AWS console right now.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

```
aws lambda create-event-source-mapping # does not support scheduling events
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to use the API to create a schedule event sources with AWS Lambda at this time.  That means it is not possible to use the AWS CLI to create the schedule.  It is also not possible to use CloudFormation to schedule a AWS Lambda function.

Unfortunately using the GUI is the only option until AWS release an API.

Answer (score -3):

We use Lambda to create print-ready file: http://blog.peecho.com/blog/using-aws-lambda-functions-to-create-print-ready-files